# Access denied for S3 triggered SQS event record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

**I currently have the following scenario:**

- A S3 bucket is set up to receive files and publish to a SQS queue an event record for each file that is created or updated.
- A bunch of kubernetes pods reading this queue, reading the file keys from the event and processing the files.

**The problem:**

Almost 50% of the times, when the k8s pod try to load the file after reading the event record, it receives an "Access Denied" permission error. When the same message comes back from flight and the pod tries to load the file again, it always does without problems.

I've already tried to set up the delivery delay to more time, didn't work.

Comment: Does the Delivery Delay fix the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I know that the Delivery Delay does not affect AWS Lambda functions that are triggered from a queue, but it should delay the ability to retrieve a new message from a queue via `ReceiveMessage()`. Have you tried setting the delay to several minutes, just to test whether it helps? There might be an Eventual Consistency issue that is causing the messages to appear in SQS before the object is fully available in the Amazon S3 bucket, but that shouldn't take more than a few seconds.

Comment: Yeah bro, I already did that. It had not effect for me :/

Comment: Did you verify that the delay actually happened? It sounds strange that it works when the message is reprocessed (after the invisibility timeout) but not with a mere delay. You could also experiment with adding a delay in the code, just to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yeah, the delay happened. Adding a sleep in the code did not work as well.